# problem sql request returns null though the it return right values in xampp SGBD

Tags: java, sql, database, xampp

This is my code i'm trying to get data from my data base but it always returns null though i've checked it well and ther is no error

[image]

i have put the same sql sentence in my SGBD XAMPP and it returns a value

[image]

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: First, do not post images on SO, post the code. Second, you ignore `SQLException` in your code. Most likely you get an exception there. Check it first.

Comment: i hv already checked it and i also removed it but the probem was not there